# Combining if statement for multiple variable in a match case in scala

Tags: scala

I am looking for a cleaner way of doing the following operation in scala

```
      val myVar1 = myObj.getMyVar1()
      val myVar2 = myObj.getMyVar2()
      val myVar3 = myObj.getMyVar3()
      val myVar4 = myObj.getMyVar4()

      if (checkSomething(myVar1)) {
          dosomething(myVar1)
      }          }
      if (checkSomething(myVar2)) {
          dosomething(myVar2)
      }    
      if (checkSomething(myVar3)) {
          dosomething(myVar3)
      }          }
      if (checkSomething(myVar4)) {
          dosomething(myVar4)
      }
```

Comment: `vars.foreach(v => if (heckSomething(v)) doSomething(v))`

Comment: Adding @Gaston Schabas's question as comment - What do you mean with a cleaner way? That code could be written in many different programming languages. Do you want to write that in a more functional style? Could you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

You can use List to store all your variables and then use filter and map

```
val list: List[_] = List(myVar1, myVar2, myVar3, myVar4)
list.filter(checkSomething).foreach(doSomething)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the **for/yield style with guard** if condition as below.

No need to mention the return type of myVars since this is Scala.

```
val myVars = List(myVar1, myVar2, myVar3, myVar4)

for {
  x <- myVars 
  if checkSomething(x)
} yield doSomething(x)
```